# Infinite smooth horizontal scrolling carousel in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel

I am trying to recreate this animation (link below) in Xamarin forms but so far not successful. Does anyone have any ideas how this might be possible?

codepen.io/wschern/pen/grXwra

Comment: It would be better to use CollectionView if you want to implement the smooth animation . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction

Comment: Check this https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8641

Answer (score 0):

You need include a timer to increase the current position:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),(Func<bool>)(() =>
{

    MainCarouselView.Position = (MainCarouselView.Position + 1) % image.Count;

    return true;
}))
```

;